# Find rows that have the same values in another column

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table.

`User  Permission 
John  1
Mary  1
Anne  1
Joe   2
Marie 2
Nick  3`

I want to select and group users with the same permission number. Is this actually possible? I have millions of different permission values.

Expected output:

`(John, Mary, Anne), (Joe, Marie), (Nick)`

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to do this in the application, after all it's just presentation. Something like:

```
SELECT user, permission
FROM T
ORDER BY permission
```

then keep track of when permission changes.

However (untested), there seems to be a [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) function that can do what you want:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user), permission
FROM T
GROUP BY permission
ORDER BY permission
```